# asp:listview and refresh list after posting to SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, listview

I have created a listview based on the below data:

```
<div class="showJournals">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListJournal" runat="server" DataSourceID="journalData" >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table runat="server" style="">
        <tr>
            <td>Finner ingen journaler.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td class="navn">
            <%# Eval("journalSentBy") %> 
            <%# Eval("journalrecvdBy") %>
        </td>
        <td class="text">
            <asp:Label ID="journalTextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("journalText") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="journalDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("journalDate") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>

    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr runat="server" style="">
            <th runat="server" class="navn">Navn</th>
            <th runat="server" class="text">Journaltekst</th>
            <th runat="server">Dato</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
        </tr>
    </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="journalData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:S2000ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [journalSentBy], [journalrecvdBy], [journalText], [journalDate] FROM [TBL_CASE_JOURNAL] WHERE ([journalCaseId] = @journalCaseId) ORDER BY [journalDate] DESC">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtcase" Name="journalCaseId" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;
</div>
```

My problem comes when i have created a function to insert New lines into the DB table and goes back to the listview, i cant get the list to be refreshed With the New data. Is there some commands or possible to create a function to handle this? Many thanks for any response concerning this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your function add:

```
ListJournal.DataBind();
```

It should work.